# CSS responsive image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I worked on a small slider ,and it was used with fixed values(pixels in my case).
I tried to make it fit the browser size.

I set the wrapper width to 90%,and the `li`'s should be each one also 100% of the wrapper..because the slider has to display only one item per slide..(and not 2).

```
#slider-wrap ul#slider li{
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   width:100%;//problomatic part
   height:400px;    
}
```

For some reason,when I set the `li` to 100%,it gets the window size..and became 100% of the window..instead of the slider-wrapper.. I'm not sure why..

This is the fiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/kL58jhou/2/

I hope the explanation was clear.

Thanks.

Comment: If you inspect your slider, you will see this: <ul id="slider" style="width: 2930px; left: -2344px;">
So, your slides take full width of the slider, which is in this case 2930px

Comment: Your fiddle looks file. There are no images.

Comment: @Armin oh sorry.. i meant i want it to be 100% of the slider wrapper..

Comment: @SunnyRGupta it's background colors right now.. will switch to images later..

Answer (score 0):

@Slashy I understood what you meant. You have a wrapper that has limited width. Inside you have absolute list that has width of 2930px(auto-calculated), and that list has list items of 100% width. So, these items of course take width of the list(2930px). On click you just move them to the left/right. If you want them to be the same width as wrapper, you should set it in your code. For example you can add

```
   $(this).css("width",sliderWidth+"px");
```

Inside your `$.each($('#slider-wrap ul li'), function() {` function
.
This is not a perfect example, because you would also have to run it on each resize of the browser.

Comment: i also thought about this! is there any other option instead of running this code on every `window.Resize()` event? @Armin

Comment: The easiest option I can come up with is working with position:absolute and z-index, but then you will lose sliding effect. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kL58jhou/3/